# Show that the following infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(2+\sin(n))^n}{n 3^n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Show that this infinite series converges
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2+\sin(n))^n}{n 3^n}$$

This is an open problem which I found in the book J. ‘‘M. Borwein and D. H. Bailey. Mathematics by Experiment: Plausible
Reasoning in the 21st century’’.

I tried wolfram apha to compute for some $n$ but I found that this is very slowly diverging sum. Also wolfram concludes that this sum is diverging by limit test but yesterday it shows that sum converges by comparsion test. Book clearly states to prove its convergence.

Any idea on how to prove its convergence and To which value does it converge?

Comment: Heuristically it should converge as $\sum x^n/n$ converges for all $|x|\lt1$ and we have $|(2+\sin{(n)})/3|\lt1$ for every value of $n$. Although there are subsequences of $n$ such that this quantity tends to $1$ so this argument may not be foolproof.

Comment: @PeterForeman That's what I thought yet that isn't enough as we could also use $\;\frac n{n+1}\;$ ,which is also always less than one...I think the limit supremum of that thing is 1, which makes things trickier

Comment: @DonAntonio I think what distinguishes this case is that probabilistically the absolute values are less than $1-\epsilon$ with a probability tending to $1$ (as $\epsilon\to0^+$) whereas the case you stated always gives this probability as $0$.

Comment: classic https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h22093